# Creating hashes from parsed HTML

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm getting second table from [this page](http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm), parse it and trying to generate hashes from this data. The problem is that each object is separated by this grey `TR` but I can only manage this by getting every single `TR` from this table.

How can I determine proper `TR` by getting those between gray ones?

For now I'm using this line to get each `TR`:

`parsed_html.css("table")[1].css("tr")`

---

**EDIT:**
I don't know if Hash is a good way for this task but here is JSON for "LIFTING AND SHORING" section (this is sample one and feel free to correct me):

```
{
  "chapter":"07",
  "title":"LIFTING AND SHORING",
  "description":"This chapter shall...",
  "section":[
    {
      "number":"00",
      "title":"GENERAL",
      "description":"",
    },

    {
      "number":"10",
      "title":"JACKING",
      "description":"Provides information relative...",
    },

    {
      "number":"20",
      "title":"SHORING",
      "description":"Those instructions necessary...",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You'll need to determine which of the `tr` elements contain `td[bgcolor]` - those are the gray rows which you then need to exclude.

Comment: Just show me a simple snaps of the desired Hash,so that I can understand which data you are trying to get,what are the keys and what are the values ?

Comment: @Babai I've added what I need in JSON in my first post. Hope you get my POV :)

Comment: @Cojoj output is not correct! where is the opening `[` ?

Comment: @Babai I'm sorry but I missed something while writing this JSON. Now it should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're using nokogiri, I'd do something like

```
#!/usr/local/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm'))

d = doc.css("table")[1] #.css("tr")

array = []

d.css('tr').each do |r|

    tds = r.css("td") # extract the td elements from this tr

    array << tds.map {|td| td.text.strip }
end

pp array
```

Comment: What does that even mean? Look it's poor form to keep changing the question

Comment: that is the second table! indexes start at 0! :)